# "I feel stress easily" vs. "I feel stressed easily"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am informed that "feel" could be a linking verb and that "[stressed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stressed)" is an adjective. So, "feel stressed" would be grammatically correct. Are these two both correct?

> I feel stressed easily.

> I feel stress easily.

---

Are the sentences made up by myself? No, it's adapted from some learning material.

[image: Screenshot with text "You are feeling stressed, and your heart is racing! What can you do to calm yourself down?]

Comment: I think the first one could be "I get/become stressed easily." **Stressed** isn't a feeling, but a state.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you. How about the second one?

Comment: I suffer from stress freqently. I am susceptible to stress. I react badly to stressful situations. It's not really about grammar, though.

Comment: I agree with Weather Vane about the first one. The second doesn't seem quite right. It suggests that stress exists but only certain people feel it. We wouldn't say, "I feel pressure easily", but "I often feel under pressure" or "I often feel pressured." "Easily" is not quite right in this context.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: There is a difference between "I am affected by small amounts of stress" versus "I notice small amounts of stress" (in the latter case, it doesn't quite bother me). "I feel stress easily" conveys to me that you easily _notice_ stress but not necessarily easily _suffer_ from it. Sometimes, these distinctions matter - though people usually intend to convey both meanings.

Comment: @Flater Ngram doesn't find a single example of "feel stress easily" or 'feel pressure easily' or 'notice stress easily' or 'notice pressure easily'. They aren't idiomatic.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Ngrams is not a record of spoken language. "I feel stress/stressed easily, and it really doesn't take much" is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

*Stress* and *stressed* are different things.

- 'Stress' is a *force* that you may feel. That force may be real, or imagined, but the *feeling* is very real. It is synonymous with '*pressure*'.
- 'Stressed' is the *state* of feeling stress.

So, feeling *stress* (or 'pressure') means you are feeling the effects of that force. Feeling *stressed* (or 'pressured') means you are experiencing the state of being under stress or pressure. So, both "I feel stress" and "I feel stressed" are equally correct.

When you add the adverb 'easily', the difference matters more. A person might say "I feel wet", but can you imagine someone saying "*I feel wet easily*"? Water causes someone to feel wet just like stress causes someone to feel stressed. It might be idiomatic to say you feel a state, but not that you feel a state easily.

Idiomatic ways to say that you become stressed easily include:

- I am prone to stress
- I easily become stressed
- I get stressed easily

Answer (score -1):

They are grammatically different, but they are both correct and in your case they more or less convey the same meaning. I would use "stressed" here, but either works.

Here's an example where the meaning is quite different:

> I feel wind easily

I quickly notice when there's a breeze or a draft

> I feel windy easily

I am often flatulent.

---

The difference is how you are using ["feel"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/feel):

> **feel**
>   VERB
>
> 1. Be aware of (a person or object) through touching or being touched.
>
>    *"I feel the wind on my skin"*
>      *"I can feel the sand between my toes"*
> 2. Experience (an emotion or sensation)
>
>    *"Airplanes make me feel sick"*
>      *"I feel horrible for pushing her over"*

For your particular example,

Comment: Thank you. "I am often flatulent" is some kind of tiny disease?

Comment: @shiqangpan Flatulence is a more polite word for farting. But you're on the right track that being sick is often expressed using "I feel [adjective]"

Comment: No regular (as in a normal person) English speaker would say: I feel windy easily.  It is actually quite funny.

Answer (score -1):

to feel stress [noun]

- Did you feel **the** stress **of** participants at that conference?
- Did you feel stressed as well?
  OR
- Did you feel stress as well?
  OR
- Did you feel that stress at that conference?

Yes, modern grammarians just love calling stressed in contexts like these with linking verbs an adjective. And you can add on the word easily:

I feel stressed easily
OR
I feel stress easily
OR
I feel easily stressed"

[feel easily stressed=on tons of sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22feel%20easily%20stressed%22&ei=dg8tYeLCEY-Jgge-sZi4Aw&oq=%22feel%20easily%20stressed%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoHCAAQRxCwAzoECCEQCjoICAAQCBAHEB46CAgAEAgQDRAeSgQIQRgAULZTWJ1dYNZjaAFwAngAgAFJiAHzA5IBATiYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwji1bqJndnyAhWPhOAKHb4YBjcQ4dUDCA8&uact=5)

Both are saying the same thing. In everyday speech, we'd *probably* use the first more than the second. The second might appear in a doctor's notes. For example: (The) patient feels stress easily.

Comment: Beware of downvoters who are misinformed.